# Hiding Buckets in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage, cyberduck

We've just moved files off of a 10 year old FTP server and are now using Google Cloud Storage for our company's files. This was setup to use the [web-hosting feature](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website) of GCS, and the [access logging capability](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-logs#introduction) was also enabled.

The access logs are dumped into a bucket. I would like to deny access to this bucket, but allow them to continue using the main GCS bucket (we use Cyberduck for this).

We are presently allowing anybody with our company's email address to read/write to the buckets in this project, by giving the "Domain" the "Storage Admin" and "Storage Object Admin" permissions. This was granted through the IAM permissions.

Comment: What account does Cyberduck act as?  You could change the ACL/IAM policy for the second bucket to be restricted to different user or service account.

Comment: I added a couple more details to my question, to directly answer your question, we are using our company's Google Apps Gmail accounts (the domain) to identify and authorize users @TravisHobrla

Comment: Could you grant that permission at a different level (not to your entire domain)?  For example, users could run as a certain service account, and administrative users with permission to access the access logs bucket could run as a more privileged service account.